# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle: How to create custom GET-method

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have configured FOSRestBundle like following:

```
fos_rest:
  param_fetcher_listener: true
  body_listener: true
  format_listener: true
  view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
  routing_loader:
    default_format: json
    include_format: false
```

In my class if extend like this

```
class PlayerController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
```

So i am able to build methods like

```
/**
 * Get all players.
 *
 * @return array
 *
 * @Rest\View
 */
public function cgetAction()
{
    $players = $this->getDoctrine()
      ->getRepository('bbbFrontendBundle:Player')
      ->findAll();

    return array('players' => $players);
}
```

which provides me a route get_players where i can reqeust all players through a GET request.

Now my question: I wanna provide a `searchAction($searchterm, $limit)` method which listens to GET and provide searchresults through elasticsearch by a given searchterm.
The problem that im facing is, all custom methods are automatically associated with the PATCH method. And with PATCH method im not able to provide parameters and get a result like i want to. How can i achieve my method to listen to GET request??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define cget action with custom suffix.
For example:

```
public function cgetSearchAction()
```